# Is it permissible to marry a girl who is from jamaat e islam?

Tags: nikah, salafi

Salamalaikum,

I have a question. I follow salafi. I wanted to know if it's permissible to marry a girl who is from jaamat e islam?

Comment: Why not? No such restrictions IN islam

Comment: okay, what if she follows bidaat like mawlid, ijtema, and others?